Couldn't user Informix.Net.Core package
I want to user Informix.Net.Core package to insert data into Informix.
connection.Open() throws exception like below:
Unable to load DLL 'iclit09b.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E) )'

My code base in .net6

The Informix .NET Core provider is not fully managed which means it needs native libraries (like the ODBC iclit09b.dll) to run.
You need to have the %INFORMIXDIR%\bin (from the Informix CSDK) in your PATH to allow the provider to load those dependencies.

@jsagrera, I have an another issue on connection.Open() like the following:
Exception occured while QueryExecution. Exception: ERROR [HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Server localhost:9089 is not listed as a dbserver name in sqlhosts. '

'localhost:9089' looks like the Db2 (Data Server Provider format) not the Informix one.
With the Informix .NET Core provider you want to use something like: string connectionString = "Database=sysmaster;Host=host1;Protocol=onsoctcp;Server=ol_informix1410_1;Service=9089;User ID=informix;Password=mypassword";

The Informix database server name is not localhost:9089, even if that's the machine:port that you connect to.

Does IBM have an official .net core informix provider?
I am using HCL Informix .NET Core Provider.

I ran Informix on docker on windows.
Installed Informix Client SDK.
Added environment variables.
Added sqlhosts file with the following content:
ol_informix1410_1 onsoctcp localhost 9089
And try to use this connection string:
string connectionString = "Database=sysmaster;Host=localhost;Protocol=onsoctcp;Server=ol_informix1410_1;Service=9089;User ID=informix;Password=mypassword";
But it didn't work, did I do something wrong?

When I install the Informix Client SDK, I have ``Informix.Net.Core.dll'' in it, can I use it?

You can either add the info to the sqlhosts or put all details in the connection string. BUT, they have to be the exact details for your Informix server. The string I wrote above was just an example. The values for all those parameters should be based on your Informix server. For example, host should be the IP (or exposed IP) of your docker container. server should match your $INFORMIXSERVER server . You can get most of that details from the Informix server sqlhosts file within the container.
Regarding .NET providers, .NET and .NET Core are include with CSDK and should work fine.

.NET Core provider uses ODBC internally, so need to configure ODBC also?

Nope, it uses the ODBC driver libraries but there is no need to configure or create any ODBC DSN for it to work.

docker run -it --name ifx -h ifx --privileged -p 9088:9088 -p 9089:9089 -p 27017:27017 -p 27018:27018 -p 27883:27883 -e LICENSE=accept ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest
I ran like above. But inside docker container sqlhosts is empty (/opt/ibm/informix/etc/sqlhosts).

That looks like the free developer edition docker image. If you have not changed the default values, the string for accessing the container should be: "Database=sysmaster;Host=localhost;Protocol=onsoctcp;Server=informix;Service=9088;User ID=informix;Password=in4mix". It will connect to the sysmaster db which shouldn't be used by client apps, but will let you validate the connection

I installed informix for windows version and can connect to it by the following connection string:
Host=localhost;Service=9090;Protocol=onsoctcp;Server=ol_informix1410;Database=test_db;User ID=informix;Password=12345;
But connection.Open()  takes longer time.
